# Keras: ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (10, 1)

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm new to keras and I'm facing this error: ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (10, 1). My input array shape is (10, 1010)

and my model is one layer only

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(10, batch_input_shape=(None, 1010),init='uniform', activation='relu'))
```

any ideas how can I fix this I tried many combinations nothing works for me?

Answer (score 0):

A clue is in the fact that the error is complaining about the dimension of the target. I suspect the target is shape `(10, 1)`, whereas the (final) layer is expecting the target to be `(None, 10)`. The model needs the target to be the same dimension as the last layer in the model. After all, if the two aren't the same dimension, how else would Keras be able to do any kinds of comparisons and ultimately give you an accuracy score?