# Keras: ValueError while doing predictions and accuracy is zero

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I wrote the following model in Keras but while doing predictions, I am encountering ValueError (stated after the code). I looked at other questions on StackOverflow but only found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324801/keras-valueerror-error-when-checking-model-target-expected-dense-1-to-have-sh) but I wasn't able to understand what the answer is saying.

I am trying to build a network which takes X as input and has a hidden of 200 neurons and finally, a sigmodial neuron to predict the output class. The objective is binary classification.

The input to the model is (n x 400) as X and (n, 1) as Y. Both X and Y are numpy arrays. The code and the error message are as follows. Also, results of the neural network are : Loss = Infinite and Accuracy = 0.0 which means something from my side is clearly wrong.

```
def create_baseline():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=400, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I train the model as follows:

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
estimator.fit(X, Y)
```

I try to predict using the following:

```
estimator.predict(X[0])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_34_input to have shape (None, 400) but got array with shape (400, 1)
```

Edit 1 : The training data X has 400 features (which are learnt from word2vec for the document). Y is a label which is only 0 and 1. I read the training file into a pandas dataframe and then use `dataframe.values` to get X and Y as numpy array.

Edit 2: Based on the answer below, I predicted from my model as `estimator.predict(train_X_vals[0].reshape(1,len(train_X_vals[0])))` and I get the following output: `array([[ nan]], dtype=float32)`

Edit 3: I predict values for 1000 X's from the training set and I get all these as nan.

Edit 4: I have about 250K training samples. Upon using all these samples, I am getting loss = nan and all predictions as nan.  But when I take a sample of 2000 samples, I start getting good values.

Edit 5: It seems my model can't process more than 2500 training samples. I tried increasing training size and on 3000 and more, everything becomes nan.

Comment: Could you provide here the full code, including some data X,Y ? (doesn't have to be your specific data, it could be just a toy example, so that the reader would be able to run your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error that you get- when you specify the input dimension, you specify the number of columns, which is 400 in your case. However, `x[0]` is just a  vector, so instead of having dimensions of the form (None, 400), its dimension is (400, 1). For example, if you define

```
x=np.random.rand(20,400)
```

The result of `x[0].shape` is `(400L,)`.

So you need to reshape your `x[0]` accordingly, for example by doing `x[0].reshape(1,len(x[0]))`.

Comment: does that mean that the model is being trained perfectly? Because I am seeing accuracy = 0 and Loss = nan (which is equivalent to Inf).

Comment: I don't think so, (accuracy supposed to be 1.0 if you are doing classification and the model is perfect). But it is hard to say what is happening without being able to run your code. If you could provide some examples of X and Y that would be helpful.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem related to the specific data that you used. I run your code with X=np.random.rand(10,400) and
Y=np.random.randint(0,2,10) and I got a reasonable loss and accuracy (both of them were numbers and not nan). Could you provide an access to your specific data?

Comment: I have about 250K training samples. Upon using all these samples, I am getting loss = nan and all predictions as nan.  But when I take a sample of 2000 samples, I start getting good values. All features are between `0.0-1.00`

Comment: Maybe some of your data is corrupted? Or has nans inside or something like that? You could try to take subsets of your data (say, to devide it into 5 sets of 50K each), run your code on each one and see which one of them produce the problem.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: However, accuracy is still zero. But predictions are not NaNs. Now they are all `1`.

Comment: Is this happen when you take smaller subset of your data as well? Also, If accuracy is 0 and all predictions are 1 on your training, it means that all the true labels are 0. Is this indeed the case?

Comment: Restarted Python and everything is fine now. Thanks!